# Set up Bandwidth Limiting Proxy?

Tags: proxy, socks5

I want to set up a proxy on an ubuntu box for my brother to torrent through and then be able to limit the bandwidth with the proxy.

I have tried looking for how to do this, but to no avail.

Comment: You can do this with iptables and or squid. See `man iptables` and look at the --quota option. If what you are doing is not working, please give a better description of what you are trying to accomplish, the problem, and your config files.

Comment: See also http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/pdf/Bandwidth-Limiting-HOWTO.pdf

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Isn't Squid for HTTP traffic?

Comment: Yes, which is why we need more information on what you want and your problem.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen "to torrent through"

Comment: torrents can be rough as they use random ports. I would use iptables but again, it is not clear what your problem is. Read the links I gave you and post more details and your configuration.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen The only thing the proxy will be used for, is for the torrenting programs. By forcing them all through this proxy, bandwidth quota can be managed.